# How to escape special characters in scriptella

Tags: escaping, character, scriptella

Please help!

I need to insert a xml string inside a varchar field in an oracle 8i legacy table.

The insert goes like this:

```
       insert into NUC_LEGACY_2_ANAC values (
         SEQ_NUC_LEGACY_2_ANAC.nextval, 
         $sinonimo, 
         'ADT', 
         'CREATE_PATIENT',
         '<CrearActualizarPaciente><sinonimo>'||$sinonimo||'</sinonimo></CrearActualizarPaciente>',
         sysdate,
         null,
         0,
         0,
         null
       );
       commit;
```

But scriptella gaves me this error:

Element type "CrearActualizarPaciente" must be declared.
Element type "sinonimo" must be declared.
The content of element type "script" must match "(include|dialect|onerror)"

I understand scriptella does not recognize the xml  like and string that must be concatenated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
'<CrearActualizarPaciente><sinonimo>'||$sinonimo||'</sinonimo></CrearActualizarPaciente>',
```

with

```
  '&lt; CrearActualizarPaciente> &lt;sinonimo>'||$sinonimo||'&lt;/sinonimo> &lt;/CrearActualizarPaciente>',
```